# What is the cause of this message?"Failed to select us running on Google Compute Engine."

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translate

As I am a Korean, I hope that I understand my poor English.

Since the API key cannot be registered in the environment variable, the API key was registered using setProperty after confirming that the API key was imported from TranslateOptions to getProperty.

Although it works successfully, an error occurs in the init of TranslateOptions.

```java
private static Translate translateSet;

static{
    System.setProperty("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "MY API KEY");
    translateSet = TranslateOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
}
public String translate(Object text, String target){
    String result = "";
    try{
        Translation translation = translateSet.translate(
        Fn.toString(text),//Object to String
        TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("ko"),
        TranslateOption.targetLanguage(target)
        );
        result = translation.getTranslatedText();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Error messages

```
----------------------------------------------------
1월 31, 2019 2:26:25 오후 com.google.auth.oauth2.ComputeEngineCredentials runningOnComputeEngine
정보: Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute Engine.
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect

1월 31, 2019 2:26:25 오후 com.google.auth.oauth2.ComputeEngineCredentials runningOnComputeEngine
정보: Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute Engine.
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect

1월 31, 2019 2:26:25 오후 com.google.auth.oauth2.ComputeEngineCredentials runningOnComputeEngine
정보: Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute Engine.
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
```

Comment: Where are you running this code? This error indicates a network problem. If you are running in Google Cloud on a Compute Engine instance, have you disabled networking via the firewall? More details please.

Comment: Currently in use by the localhost.
But the Internet is connected and translation is success.